# jquery plugins inheritance and requirejs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, inheritance, requirejs

I wants to define an API which load some jqueryui plugins with requirejs.
Definition of the plugins to load is made in the DOM content through data nodes:

```
<div id="pluginContainer">
    <div data-plugin="fooPlugin"/>
    <span data-plugin="barPlugin"/>
</div>
```

The following code source try to load all plugins inside the container:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'container'], function() {
        // when widget container is loaded, we load the plugins inside #pluginContainer
        $('#pluginContainer').container();
    });
</script>
```

The plugin container code source is the following one (in the file /js/container.js):

```
define(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($) {
    'use strict';
    $.widget('ns.container', {
    /**
     * container constructor
     * @private
     */
    _create: function() {
        this._initPlugin();
    },
    /**
     * load plugins into the container
     * @private
     */ 
    _initPlugin: function() {
        var $plugin, $pluginType;
        this.element.find('*[data-plugin]').each(function(index, plugin) {
            $plugin = $(plugin);
            pluginType = $plugin.data('plugin');
            require([pluginType], function() {
            try {
                console.log("instanciate plugin type '" + pluginType+"'");
                $plugin[pluginType]();
            } catch (e) {
                console.error("Cannot instanciate plugin '"+pluginType+"'");
            }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

My problem is that it seems that some plugins are not well loaded: The code source above display the following console output:

```
 create fooPlugin
 Instanciate plugin type 'fooPlugin'
 Cannot instanciate plugin 'barPlugin'
 create extendedPlugin
 create barPlugin
```

And I expect:

```
 create fooPlugin
 Instanciate plugin type 'fooPlugin'
 create extendedPlugin
 create barPlugin    
 Instanciate plugin type 'barPlugin'
```

I suppose that this is the plugin organization which is responsible of that. They use the following one:

```
AbstractPlugin
    |_FooPlugin
    |_ExtendedPlugin
        |_BarPlugin
```

All my plugins have a base structure coming from the abstractPlugin (defined in the /js/shared/abstract.js file):

```
/**
 * abstractPlugin widget plugin definition
 * This plugin define base structure for all plugins used
 */
define(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($) {
    'use strict';
    $.widget('ns.abstractPlugin', {
        _create: function() {}
    });
});
```

Foo plugin (defined in the /js/foo/foo.js file) inherit directly from abstractPlugin:

```
/**
 * fooPlugin widget plugin definition
 */
define(['jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'abstractPlugin'], function($) {
    'use strict';
    $.widget('ns.fooPlugin', {
        _create: function() {
            console.log('create fooPlugin');
        }
    });
});
```

But BarPlugin  (defined in the /js/bar/bar.js file) inherit from an intermediate plugin, called extendedPlugin (defined in the /js/shared/extended.js file):

```
 /**
 * extendedPlugin widget plugin definition
 */
 define(['jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'abstractPlugin'], function($) {
    'use strict';
    $.widget('ns.extendedPlugin', $.ns.abstractPlugin, {
    _create: function() {
        console.log('create extendedPlugin');
    }
    }); 
});
```

Bar plugin content is the following one:

```
 /**
  * Bar widget plugin definition
  */
 define(['jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'extendedPlugin'], function($) {
      'use strict';
      $.widget('ns.barPlugin', $.ns.extendedPlugin, {
    _create: function() {
        console.log('create barPlugin');
    }
      });
 });
```

According with some answers available from this website, require is used for immediate use, define is used for later usage. So my code should be ok.

So my question is: How can I ensure that when I use require all the plugin dependancies will also be loaded?

The requirejs configuration used in this example is the following one:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            abstractPlugin: 'js/shared/abstract',
            fooPlugin: 'js/foo/foo',
            extendedPlugin: 'js/shared/extended',
            barPlugin: 'js/bar/bar',
            container: "js/container"
        }
    }
}
```

Thank in advance for every kind of tip you can provide me.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I didn't took the time to extract your code and try it in any jsfiddler, but you might be missing 'abstractPlugin' defined in the Bar widget.

something like this. Perhaps worth a try?

```
/**
* Bar widget plugin definition
*/
define(['jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'abstractPlugin',  'extendedPlugin'],        
 function($) {
  'use strict';
     $.widget('ns.barPlugin', $.ns.extendedPlugin, {
        _create: function() {
        console.log('create barPlugin');
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hello Edward, thank you for your answer. I'm discovering the requirejs concept within this project and I'm suprised that I should mention the extendedPlugin's dependancies in the barPlugin. Is it the appropriate way to process with requirejs? But unfortunatly, this doesn't solve my issue.